# Error in writing Annotations using Room Persistence library - Android

Tags: android, android-room

I am using `Room Persistence Library` to create a database in my android application.

When trying to make a class named `User` as an `Entity`, I added `@Entity` annotation above my `User` class but android studio displays an error saying `cannot resolve symbol Entity`.

```
@Entity               <--------cannot resolve symbol Entity
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey                     <--------cannot resolve symbol PrimaryKey
    private String userName;
    private String userPhoneNumber;
}
```

I also tried to add `@PrimaryKey` annotation to one of the data members of `User` class but i get the same error.

What am i doing wrong here ?

**Logs from Gradle Console**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebugAndroidTest
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 38s
22 actionable tasks: 22 executed
```

**Gradle build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.Nick.phonebook_database"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Post the logs from the `Gradle Console` but not the `Logcat`.

Comment: Ok, that's weird. It is supposed to give an error.

Comment: Btw your `@PrimaryKey` requires also `@NonNull` since it is a String.

Comment: Weird because I am expecting to see an error info in `Gradle Console` but since it does not appear in your case.

Comment: oh ok, i thought you meant android studio is suppose to give an error :P

Comment: Can you post your `Gradle` imports also?

Comment: I don't know how to check Gradle imports. Where can i view them ?

Comment: It's a file in your app folder named like `build.gradle`. It looks like [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#module-level), below you will see `dependencies` that is your import.

Comment: Ok, got it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the Room dependency also.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-beta1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-beta1"

}
```

After adding the dependency click `Sync Now`.

Comment: Quick question, Why doesn't Android Studio automatically adds these imports ?

Comment: Glad it helps. `Why doesn't Android Studio automatically adds these imports?` Because Google do not force you to use this library, you have the freedom to disregard this library and not to use it in your project, being said we also have other library that does similar things like `GreenDao` for example :)